# How to delete a widget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Actually im having 2 Qwidgets say "Widget" , "NewWidget". I'm calling "NewWidget" in "Widget" keypress event and viced versa,

```
void Widget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *qv)
{
  // i want to delete "Widget" here before i call "NewWidget"
   NewWidget *newWidget = new NewWidget();
   newWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color:black;");
   newWidget->setGeometry(0,0,640,480);    
   newWidget->show();
}
```

I want to delete or destroy the "Widget" before calling "NewWidget"

Comment: Could you please explain why do you need to delete Widget in its keyPressEvent ?

Comment: @demonplus: im running this executable in ARM based board which is having very less memory.Actually im using 4 widgets in my application,so if i delete the widget while calling another , i can save the memory thats the reason im looking for

Comment: While you always can use delete for a widget, you need to think about parent-child relationship existing for widgets in qt. When you are deleting parent, child will be also deleted. Could you please edit your question and describe the architecture of your application in more detail?

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri: perhaps having a Qt application (or any rich GUI app) on a RAM starved ARM board is a mistake. Did you consider making a web application instead (so run on your ARM board some specialized web server, perhaps using some HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), and interacting with your board and embedded app thru a web browser, as many appliances do)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
this->deleteLater();
```

It will attempt to destroy the widget when the function exits.

It sounds dangerous/bad to destroy the current widget when you are busy inside a member function of the widget that you want to destroy. Try the above code but otherwise think about redesigning your interactions.

Comment: IIRC, `deleteLater` won't destroy the widget at function exit, but inside the Qt event loop (so when all the current loop processing has been done, and before processing the *next* event)